# Maven - Place WSDL auto-generated code in different folders

Tags: maven-2, cxf, wsimport

I have a directory with, say 2, wsdl files - a.wsdl and b.wsdl. Using Maven, I need to auto-generate types from the wsdl files but place the sources in different folders. What I mean is I need to place the types generated from a.wsdl in target/generated/atypes and those from b.wsdl in target/generated/btypes. The reason for asking this is a.wsdl and b.wsdl share some common types and when the auto-generation goal is run, it overwrites the type source generated earlier from a.wsdl.

It seems this is not possible with the existing plugins - mojo, cxf-code-gen etc. Or is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

It seems that we can specify the wsdl to read and the output directory for plugin execution.  Try to have two executions (with different ID) and each of them configured for each of your wsdl.

Comment: Not only should the generated sources be placed in different folders but different namesapces too, since the types are shared.

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with generating code to different folders as what the title and your content suggest.  Though I haven't tried, but in the link I quoted, there is an example to let you provide JAX_WS binding file, for which it claimed to allow you to specify the package name CXF use.